# Fuzzy Logic Composition

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I want to know when to use max-min composition and max product composition. I'm pretty sure I understand how to compute them, but I notice that even though they're both supposed to be performing composition I get different answers. Can someone explain how they can both represent the same action yet yield different results? When should I use one over the other?
I've been learning about fuzzy logic on my own and unfortunately I have seen more examples of this sort of thing in this field. I've looked online for answers and by and all I've seen is people pretending this isn't weird and something to wonder about. Thank you for your time.